# Oracle, error while exporting schema

Tags: linux, export, oracle

I'm using a command:

```
$ exp userid=apex_public_user/apex_public_user OWNER=apex_public_user DIRECT=Y CONSISTENT=Y FILE=/home/oracle/apex_public_user.dmp
```

and getting following output:

```
Export: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fr May 18 11:55:20 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle. All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Export done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 4063 encountered
ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_UTL" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_UTL"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_EXP", line 87
ORA-06512: at line 1
EXP-00083: The previous problem occurred when calling SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_EXP.schema_info_exp
. exporting foreign function library names for user APEX_PUBLIC_USER
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions for user APEX_PUBLIC_USER
About to export APEX_PUBLIC_USER's objects ...
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export APEX_PUBLIC_USER's tables via Direct Path ...
. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting triggers
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
. exporting job queues
. exporting refresh groups and children
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 4063 encountered
ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_UTL" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_UTL"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_EXP", line 87
ORA-06512: at line 1
EXP-00083: The previous problem occurred when calling SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_EXP.schema_info_exp
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully with warnings.
```

What can be wrong with the way how I export a schema?
The same error appears while exporting any other schemas.

Comment: Is this a production database, because it's very broken? You need to run some scripts to recreate internal database objects....

Comment: Yes, this base is in use on the server.

Answer (score 5):

Your database is unhappy.

Login to your Linux box as the DB owner user (usually `oracle`), restart it & then do the following to recreate the broken data dictionary objects:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

@?/rdbms/admin/catrepr.sql

@?/rdbms/admin/catrep.sql 

@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

Restart the database once done.

This is an unusual situation to be in - Has the DB been recently upgraded?

Comment: Thank you Phil! I don't have catrepr.sql file, though. I have catreps.sql instead. So, should I do the following: 1) shutdown 2) startup 3) run scripts 4) shutdown 5) startup?

Comment: Yes. In that order